Alt+other modifier+r not recognizing key down event of r | Windows
Infos:

Windows 11 Home 23H2
Razer Blackwidow Elite Keyboard

I have the combination Ctrl+Alt+R in VS Code for running a Python script. Today I realized that this shortcut doesn't work anymore. I went into the shortcut settings and tried to reassign this shortcut to the action. There is no possibility to write the shortcut, but rather to press it. There I saw that VS Code recognizes the Ctrl and Alt keys but not the r. First, I thought it was on VS Code's side. But then I opened a keyboard tester website, which simply shows you what keys you press. This is what I got:

any modifier+Alt+R: key down event of r not recognized, but key up event recognized
any modifier+Alt+any key other than r: works fine
Alt+R: works fine

So the only event that doesn't work is the key down event of r when pressing Modifier+Alt+R. Which explains why VS Code wouldn't recognize it, VS probably only listens to the key down. I already tried to kill all Razer software tasks, like Razer Synapse, which did nothing. I have the same language pack activated as before. It's probably a defect driver or Windows Update. Also, I can't think of anything I've done that could've caused this. On my Laptop I have Windows 11 Home 24H2 (idk why I don't get the 24H2 on my PC) and it works perfectly fine. Do you guys have any idea what the problem is?

Microsoft has a page about Troubleshooting keybindings for VS Code.
